# Java Apache FTPClient: How to know my current directory

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

My question is simple: i'm using the Apache commons.net API in a simple app which connects to an FTP, i can change the working directory with the changeWorkingDirectory method. but... how can i know my current directory whitout changing it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
printWorkingDirectory()
```

Returns the pathname of the current working directory. [Here's the reference](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#printWorkingDirectory%28%29).